# How to use Mori's superpixels Matlab code on Windows

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, pixel

How to use Mori's superpixels Matlab code (http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~mori/research/superpixels/)  on Windows?

i ran mex and downloaded the segbench.Readme file in segbench says 
(1) For the image and segmentation reading routines in the Dataset
directory to work, make sure you edit Dataset/bsdsRoot.m to point to
your local copy of the BSDS dataset.

(2) Run 'gmake install' from this directory to build everything.  You
should then probably put the lib/matlab directory in your MATLAB path.

(3) Read the Benchmark/README file.

For the 1st step, I changed the path in bsdsRoot.m as C:\Users\rajan\Desktop\superpixels which have the file i want to segment.

For the 2nd step  I ran command gmake install in terminal and i got

C:\Users\rajan\Desktop\superpixels\segbench>gmake install
gmake[1]: Entering directory `c:/Users/rajan/Desktop/superpixels/segbench/Util'

GNUmakefile-library:26: *** mexSuffix not defined.  Stop.
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `c:/Users/rajan/Desktop/superpixels/segbench/Util'

Comment: Please try and when you get stuck (and have searched for the solution) update the question. If you don't get stuck just accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly adapted the explanation given on the [website](http://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~mori/research/superpixels/code/).

- Run mex on each .c file in the yu_imncut directory
- Obtain mfm-pb boundary detector code from 
  http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/projects/vision/grouping/segbench/
- Change path names in sp_demo.m and pbWrapper.m
- Run sp_demo.m

Comment: how to change the path names, second matlab crashes during ncutting, can you help me in this. thanks